# Assign value to list

Tags: excel

First and foremost. I'm totally new to "programming" in Excel.

I'm trying to make a price calculator, that calculates the price when I use my printer.
The sheet contains list, so I don't need to type in numbers but can choose between some options.

I would like options within the list to have a value.

My sheet contains theese information.
**Description, Amount, Single/duplex, Format, Printing price, Paper price, Total price.**

**Description:** Could be "Printing an invitation for my brother"
**Amount:** Amount printet
**Single/Duplex:** A list containing "Single" and "Duplex"
**Format:** A list containing "A4", "SRA3" and "SRA3 HiGloss"
**Printing price:** The total price

This is how it's calculated:
**'Format' + ('Amount' x 'Single/duplex') = 'Printing price'**

I would like to assign theese values to the list options:

**Single/Duplex**
  Per page (singlex): 0,6
Per page (duplex): 1,2

**Format:**
  A4. paper: 0,2
  SRA3 High Gloss: 1,25
  SRA3: 1

**Example**

```
Description Amount      Single/Duplex       Format          Printing price
Invitations 30          Duplex              SRA3 HiGloss    61,25
```

The calculation for this example looks like this:
**'Format' + ('Amount' x 'Single/duplex') = 'Printing price'**
**1,25+(30*2)**

Does anyone know about this???

Comment: Kenneth, not exactly sure what question you are trying to get answered.  You might get better results if you ask a specific question.

Comment: Programming in quotes?  That hurts.  Do you want VBA or worksheet formulas?

Comment: Maybe take a look at: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP100705161033.aspx

Comment: I have edited the question... Does it make more sence now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a price lookup sheet and have the prices laid out in table form i.e.

```
A          B

Single  0.6

Duplex  1.3

A4      0.2
```

And so on…

You can then use the vlookup function to turn the options given into their value counterpart

=`VLOOKUP(B3,Price_lookup!A1:B20,2,FALSE)`

You can then use this as the basis for building your formula

EDIT:

Ok here is a very rough example in excel but it works. You can unhide the columns to show how it works

http://www.easy-share.com/1910066813/Stack_example.xls

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but I can't seem to get it to work... Can you possibly make an Excel sheet, upload it (http://www.easy-share.com/) and share the link with me??

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Fantastic! It works like a charm! :-)
The only thing I need now, it how to replicate/copy the lines? When I copy the lines, the code refer to wrong cells. I can do it by hand power...